# Wrong color of my point regarding colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf

The color of my diagram point is wrong if I look at my colorbar! What is the reason? The point should be not red! (Look at the scale of the colorbar)

This point: **0.63  3745 1000000**

My Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} %Für die Darstellung
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{ \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,set layers=standard, 
mark layer=axis background,colorbar sampled,only marks,view={0}{90}, colorbar style={yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult,samples=20}] %Drehung
\addplot[
scatter,mark=square*,only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]table {
x y  myvalue
0.2  100 1
0.35  2000 100
0.35  2000 100
0.63  3745 1000000
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with wrong? 1 and 100 is blue and 100000 is red -- looks ok to me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fischer thx for your answer but look at the caption of the colorbar ....

Comment: it should be red from 3,98*10 power of 6 not from 1000 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only changes the ticklabels at the colorbar.

Maybe you are looking for something like:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz too
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% <- added
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{ \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,set layers=standard, 
  mark layer=axis background,colorbar sampled,only marks,
  colorbar style={
    yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^(\tick-2)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},%<- changed
    scaled y ticks=manual: {$\cdot10^2$}{#1},%<- added
    samples=20
  }
]
\addplot[
  scatter,mark=square*,only marks,
  point meta=lg10(\thisrow{myvalue})%<- changed
]table {
x y  myvalue
0.2  100 1
0.35  2000 100
0.63  3745 1000000
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please repost your answer on TeXwelt?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you scale your values properly? Your declaration

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{ \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}}
```

seems to have no effect whatsoever on the rest of your exemple (it can be commented out w/o giving an error or any visible change in the produced pdf).
That usually means you have only declared the function, you are never using it.

Comment: ok your are right. But why is the last point red? Look at the log. scale of the colorbar. The value 1000000 is yellow/blue

Comment: If you intend tu use a log_10, but you use a natural log, your values will be ln(10) or ~2.3 times too large.